# Kotlin http request with khttp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, kotlin, request

I need to pass data in this format(Rails 5 api)

```
{"user"=>{"mail"=>"", "password"=>""}
```

But with khttp it looks like this

```
{"user"=>"{mail=, password=}"}
```

My code is pretty simple

```
khttp.post(
            url = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/users/login",
            data = hashMapOf<String, Map<String, String>>("user" to hashMapOf("mail" to email, "password" to password))
    )
```

But it works wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, so I'll just do it here.
You have not mentioned what solutions you have tried so here is my option:

Change:

```
data = hashMapOf<String, Map<String, String>>("user" to hashMapOf("mail" to email, "password" to password))
```

to:

```
data = hashMapOf<String, Map<String, String>>("user" to hashMapOf("mail" to """$email""", "password" to """$password"""))
```

Perhaps it's at least worth a shot. Good luck